# My S3 life-cycle policy is not working, how can I debug?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have a lifecycle policy setup in the AWS Console. In my S3 bucket, it has a folder called "backups". My policy has a prefix of `"backups"` and current and previous transition to glacier set to 1 day after creation. S3 files are still shown as Standard and nothing in Glacier.

I have waited a month to see if it was slow. But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

To test this, I did the following:

- Created a new **Amazon S3 bucket**
- Created a `backups` **folder** through the S3 management console
- **Uploaded** a file to the `backups` folder
- Added a Lifecycle Rule with a **filter** of `backups` (displayed in the console as "prefix backups" for **current** version to **Glacier** after 1 day

[image: Lifecycle configuration]

I then waited a couple of days and it transitioned to Glacier:

[image: Transitioned to Glacier]

**Bottom line:** It can take a couple of days for the transition to happen.